# npm install: RangeError: port should be >= 0 and < 65536: 98721

Tags: node.js, npm

I was using npm install normally until one day i got this error:

```
30 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular
31 verbose stack RangeError: port should be >= 0 and < 65536: 98721
31 verbose stack     at Socket.connect (net.js:917:13)
31 verbose stack     at Agent.exports.connect.exports.createConnection (net.js:92:35)
31 verbose stack     at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:194:16)
31 verbose stack     at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:166:23)
31 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
31 verbose stack     at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
31 verbose stack     at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:126:25)
31 verbose stack     at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:193:41)
31 verbose stack     at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:89:8)
31 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
32 verbose cwd D:\repo\lib
33 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
34 error argv "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "angular"
35 error node v0.12.4
36 error npm  v2.10.1
37 error port should be >= 0 and < 65536: 98721
38 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
38 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It looks like a proxy issue.  But I really can't figure out what went wrong.

Any ideas?

Further information:

I am using Windows 10.

I have recently installed MongoDB

My Git also report some proxy issue

I have no idea where to configure the proxy in windows (I checked the IE setting.  It is clean.  I dont think it is where I could set though)

---------------------------------------------------Updates on 20170215-----------------------------------------------

It seems that it is not related to npm version.  I updated to node v7.5.0 / npm v4.1.2 and I still got the same error message.

-------------------------------------------------Further Updates on 20170215-------------------------------------------

Ok I figured out.  The proxy through port 98721 is somehow configured by a mysterious service(I have not found out which one) as a environment variable.  After removing that, things are working as normal again.

Thanks all!

Comment: Did you change the port number in the proxy configuration recently?

Comment: Since you are using [end-of-life version of Node](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts-schedule) you won't likely to get support from Node/NPM authors. Have you tried [updating to Node v6](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)?

Comment: @NehalJWani i think the proxy setting has changed.  But not done by me.  My Git also reported some proxy issue.  Where can i see it?

Comment: @Pavlo I updated to node v7.5.0 / npm  v4.1.2.  I got the same error.

Comment: @Chen if you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using outdated Node so it may not work for you for some specific use case and there may be not much you can do. But it may not be related to the version of Node, you never know.

If I were you then I would grep for 98721 - because this is the port number that it is trying to use. See your npm config, your proxy config and try to find that number because this is not a valid port number and if it is set somewhere then it needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks.  That is a good thought.  I did check my npm config and ports listening.  It seems neither is using 98721.  I do agree that there is somewhere that set the port.  But I am still having difficulty finding where

Comment: @Chen When all else fails you can try `grep -R 98721 /` or some Windows equivalent of searching the entire file system for that number.

Answer (score 0):

A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 0 to 65535.
You can't give port number more than 65535.